# Create objects dynamically and run BFS

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I want to modify the code below for getting data from file dynamically and run the BFS. I have tried with loop but i am stuck on how i will make dynamic connection of the nodes using the anonymous objects.

```
    Node nA=new Node("101");
    Node nB=new Node("102");
    Node nC=new Node("103");
    Node nD=new Node("104");
    Node nE=new Node("105");

    //Create the graph, add nodes, create edges between nodes
    Graph g=new Graph();
    g.addNode(nA);
    g.addNode(nB);
    g.addNode(nC);
    g.addNode(nD);
    g.addNode(nE);

    g.setRootNode(nA);

    g.connectNode(nA,nB);
    g.connectNode(nA,nC);
    g.connectNode(nA,nD);
    g.connectNode(nD,nE);
```

There will be an edge file containing the connected nodes.My sample code is below

```
String[] nodes = {"1","2","3","4"};
ArrayList<Node> Nodelist = new ArrayList<Node>();

        //create node objects
        for(String val : nodes) {
            Nodelist.add(new Node(val));
        }

        //create graph nodes from array nodelist 
        Graph g = new Graph();
        for(Node val : Nodelist) {
            g.addNode(val);

        }
         g.setRootNode(Nodelist.get(0));
        //then in loop to create connection between nodes from file in structure [101,102] , [102,103] ...
        for(){
           int[] arr = file.split(",")
           g.connectNode(arr[0],arr[1])
        }
```

My problem here is with the object names.I have tried using anonymous object and then adding them in addNode() But how i will create the connection of the nodes that will be read from file using the anonymous objects array.I don't know if i am clear what i am trying to achieve.

How i can add them in HashMap but using same key and array of values.I have tried with arraylist but saves only the last value.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is having a way to find a node by it's value. You can have it by replacing the list of nodes with a map, where node's value is a key (assumption: each value is different).

```
Map<String, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

for (String val: nodes) {
    nodeMap.put(val, new Node(val));
}
```

Later on to connect nodes get them from `nodeMap` by their value.

Comment: So i will read the file put the source node as key and target node as value.Then with a for loop to make node object iterating the key, the same keys for graph and finally based on value to find the key and create the connection